# Greenshot won't let me uninstall

Tags: uninstall, greenshot

I'm using two accounts on my computer, one is personal, the other one for work. I have greeshot installed on both of them, but it only works on one of these accounts. Unfortunately it doesn't work on the one where I need it most – the app won't react to the printscreen button. I have no idea how to set it up, I've read here that office OneNote or Dropbox might be blocking it, I believe it's not my case. I also turned off the option to use the custom printscreen app from Windows 10 with the PrtSc button.

So I'm trying to uninstall Greenshot, so I can try to set it up once again, but it always tells me the app is already running. So now I cannot use it and I cannot uninstall it either.

Comment: Set up a temporary Administrator Account and uninstall it from there. There is normally just one installation even if multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

As @John already mentioned in the comments,  you should rather install the software globally for all users, not once for every user. If you cannot do so because you don't have the permissions, I suggest to use the portable (ZIP) version of Greenshot instead, you can read more about it here: https://getgreenshot.org/faq/in-which-cases-should-i-use-the-zip-package-instead-of-the-installer/

If the system says Greenshot is already running, look for the G icon in your systray. Right-click it and select "Exit".

---

*Disclosure: I am member of the Greenshot team.*